# Why does this script work as expected in 'curl', but not in the browser?

Tags: browser, script, http

I have a script which when accessed with the HTTP protocol will send some data, pause for a few seconds, then send some more data, repeating until all the data is sent.

When I access it in `curl`, it behaves as expected, and sends the data piece by piece. However, if i try to access the page in a browser, nothing is displayed on the screen until the **entire** script has finished running, several seconds later.

You can observe this behavior (temporarily) by accessing the URL

```
curl 'http://50.80.82.137:8000'
```

Then try the URL again in a browser and notice how the script waits for about 7 seconds before it loads anything, even though it should have access to the first lines immediately.

What is the source of this behavior?

---

It's written in NodeJS, and [I put it up on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/99016ee3f3184f77da0d) for reference. However, in this case I'm assuming the language involved is irrelevant (which is why I asked it on *SuperUser* instead of *StackOverflow*, and any script which has a "pause" before sending data will behave in a similar fashion.

Comment: I'm assuming the browser buffers the data to make the HTML easier to parse, but I'm not sure where to find details on or reference works regarding this behavior.

Comment: the q is fine here but you might get a broader user base if you asked this on SO and it may be ok on SO

Comment: @barlop _Completely_ off topic (so I will delete this comment when you have read it), your profile has had 1,886 views over the last four years, yet you haven't added any description, nor a link to your website. You are missing out on a lot of free (and well deserved) publicity.

Answer (score 3):

A web browser can't start processing a web page until the *entire* HTML document has completed downloading. Once the HTML has downloaded it can be parsed and rendered, but not before.

Curl doesn't need to wait for the whole document since it doesn't parse anything, it just prints everything to `StdOut` as soon as it arrives.

Use client-side tools (Javascript, CSS, etc.) to affect client-side behavior, not the network protocol.

Comment: Is there any documentation on that which you could supplement your answer with? (or even a link to the relevant part of FireFox's source code which shows this "waiting" behavior)